# How to store arbitrary number of inputs from user?

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, storage

Just wondering how I would store the inputs for an average sum of square roots problem.

The user can input as many numbers as they until they type 'end'

here is what i have for that

```
while(True):
    x = input("Enter a number please:")
    if x == 'end':
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

You can append these values to a list. Sum and then divide by the length for the average.

```
nums = []
while True:
    x = input("Enter a number:")
    if x == 'end':
        avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
        print("And the average is....", avg)
        break
    elif x.isdigit():
        nums.append(int(x))
    else:
        print("Try again.")
```

Comment: thanks a buddy of mine suggested i append the values as well was not quite sure how to do it until now!

Answer (score 1):

The next thing you'd want to learn about is a data structure such a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). You can then add items to the list on the fly with `list.append`.

However, it's noteworthy that where ever you're learning Python from will certainly go over lists at one point or another.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to store all the x values given, just use a list. l = [] l.append(x).